# Why does the angular velocity use $r$ instead of $R$?

Tags: energy-conservation, potential-energy, rotational-kinematics, moment-of-inertia, angular-velocity

I am calculating final velocity of a Maxwell wheel rotating and translating down due to gravity with energy. I split the kinetic energy into translational and rotational kinetic energy. I am little confused on the rotational kinetic energy part. If the moment of inertia use $R$ then why can't we use $R$ for the angular velocity part. A diagram is below

[image: Maxwell updated]

[image: equation]

Comment: You should show the actual problem. "The angular velocity part" is not a meaningful description.

Comment: For the tangential velocity of the center of mass, v = rω.

Answer (score 3):

Using both R and r would give the same result for the angular velocity, since they both have the same angular velocity, the rate at which the angle changes is the same for both cases. however other parts of your equation might be dependant on the R you choose. But in general for a wheel spinning, the angular velocity atleast, is the same for both,

Edit:

the tanential velocity is different however.